# Get all the Scopes in an AngularJS aplication

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering if there is a way to get all the Scopes in an AngularJS application, so I can manipulate all of them in the same level and organize them in a directive way or order?

Or if there is any way to get all the Scopes of the instances of a directive?

In case that this is not possible - could you explain why or provide me some ideas how would you approach this need?

Comment: You can use `$rootScope` to have global access from all your scopes...or you could write a method that traverses up the `$scope` chain by checking the `$parent`

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to do this in a well-organized application. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: You can use main controller which you can define at the top of your index.html 
Define that scope as an object and you can use the same scope variable across your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$scope` objects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) are all linked lists under the hood. While it isn't necessarily recommended, you can use the private properties of scope to traverse that chain from the `$rootScope`, or whatever starting point you want down.

Below is a simple example of building out an `<ul>` with a directive to spit out each scope and associated `$id` into that list, preserving the hierarchy.

```js
(function() {

  function ShowScope($rootScope) {

    function renderScope(scope, elem, level) {
      var level = (level || 1);
      var li = angular.element('<li>');
      var p = angular.element('<p>');
      p.text(scope.$id);

      li.addClass('level-' + level);
      li.append(p);

      if (scope.$$childHead) {

        var ul = angular.element('<ul>');
        
        renderScope(scope.$$childHead, ul, level + 1);
        
        li.append(ul);
      }
      
      if(scope.$$nextSibling){
        renderScope(scope.$$nextSibling, elem, level);
      }

      elem.append(li);
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function() {

          elem.empty();

          var ul = angular.element('<ul>');
          ul.addClass('list-unstyled');
          renderScope($rootScope, ul);
          elem.append(ul);
        });
      }
    };
  }
  ShowScope.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

  angular.module('scope-app', [])
    .directive('showScope', ShowScope);

}());
```

```css
.level-1{
  background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.level-2{
  background-color:rgb(200, 0, 0);
}

.level-3{
  background-color:rgb(150, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- -->
<div class="container" ng-app="scope-app" ng-init="nums=[1,2,3,4,5]">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <show-scope></show-scope>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div ng-repeat="n1 in nums">
      <p ng-repeat="n2 in nums">
        {{n1}}:{{n2}}
      </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```